# group by hour exclude last hour where less data

Tags: sql-server

i have table where there is column  starttime datetime is availble for diffrent dates and time with 15 min duration of data like

```
2017-05-31 13:00:00
2017-05-31 13:15:00
2017-05-31 13:30:00
2017-05-31 13:45:00
2017-05-31 14:00:00
2017-05-31 14:15:00
2017-05-31 14:30:00
2017-05-31 14:45:00
2017-05-31 15:00:00
2017-05-31 15:15:00
```

Now i want to fetch data and group by according to hour but only till that last hour where all mins are availble like 2017-05-31 14:45:00 in this case.

in between missing data does not a matters only last hour data  matters.

Comment: ,What is your expected output and which DBMS are you using.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you expecting just `2017-03-31 14:45:00` as your output from the above dataset?  If so, is this because it is the latest hour that has a record for `00`, `15`, `30` and `45` minutes whereas the hour `15:00` doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you could use the following query

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    DateValue datetime
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    DateValue
)
VALUES
('2017-05-31 13:00:00'),
('2017-05-31 13:15:00'),
('2017-05-31 13:30:00'),
('2017-05-31 13:45:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:00:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:15:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:30:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:45:00'),
('2017-05-31 15:00:00'),
('2017-05-31 15:15:00')

;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
          count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(sd.DateValue as date),datepart(hour,sd.DateValue) ) AS CountHour
    FROM @SampleData sd
)
SELECT  TOP 1 
       t.DateValue
FROM temp t
WHERE t.CountHour = 4 -- all mins are avaiable
ORDER BY t.DateValue DESC
```

Returns

```
DateValue
2017-05-31 14:45:00.000
```

Comment: You should partition by both the date and hour. Otherwise this solution might not work if the input data covers multiple days.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you only want to see the hours if there are 4 records for that hour. You can simply group by the hour and use having.

```
declare @table table (starttime datetime)
insert into @table values
('2017-05-31 13:00:00'),
('2017-05-31 13:15:00'),
('2017-05-31 13:30:00'),
('2017-05-31 13:45:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:00:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:15:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:30:00'),
('2017-05-31 14:45:00'),
('2017-05-31 15:00:00'),
('2017-05-31 15:15:00')


Select dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,starttime), cast(cast(starttime as date)as datetime)) aggrHour
from @table
group by dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,starttime), cast(cast(starttime as date)as datetime))
having count(starttime) = 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You could copy and or alter the table first and take a substring of the datetime up to the hour.

Alternatively use CASE. Although very verbose and this example wouldn't work across multiple days.

```
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN datetime LIKE '% 13%' THEN '13'
    WHEN datetime LIKE '% 14%' THEN '14'
    ...
END
```

Comment: Why use string manipulation when the `datepart(hour,<Date Value>)` function exists?